# Сброс буфера ввода

Tags: c, windows

Имеется вот такой кусочек кода:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define loginPwdSize 65
#define noteSize 513

void main() {
char pwdForEncode[loginPwdSize],
    note[noteSize];
while (true) {
    system("cls");
    printf("Enter password for encoding: ");
    fgets(pwdForEncode, sizeof(pwdForEncode), stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nAdd note: ");
    fgets(note, sizeof(note), stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("%s\n%s", pwdForEncode, note);
    system("pause");
    }
}
```

Собственно, вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы при вводе символов, коих больше, чем считывает `fgets`, они не оставались в, мм, буфере?
Иначе я ввожу `~100` символов при первом приглашении ввода, он читает 65 штук, остальное отправляет сразу во второй `fgets`, и, естественно, так быть не должно.
Вот тут `fflush(stdin)`, но эффекта нет: всё равно отправляет "остаток" во второй `fgets`. С `_flushall();` немного иначе: он срабатывает, но выборочно, раз через два, почему - не могу понять.

Компилятор: "*Оптимизирующий компилятор Майкрософт С/С++ версии 19.00.23506*"

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\ConsoleApplication2.pch"
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, [минимальный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и укажите точную версию компилятора и строку компиляции. Например, [вот такой](https://pastebin.com/9VSSvAHt) пример с `fflush(stdin)` у меня заработал.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mKbZLf23 (надеюсь, это то, что нужно)

"Оптимизирующий компилятор Майкрософт С/С++ версии 19.00.23506" - оно?

Насчёт строки компиляции: я понял, что вы спрашиваете, но не знаю, где в VS это посмотреть. Единственное что нашёл:
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\ConsoleApplication2.pch"

Comment: Оно. Добавьте, пожалуйста, эту информацию прямо в вопрос с оформлением как код - кнопка "править" находится под тэгами.

Comment: У меня все работает.

Comment: А у меня, почему-то, нет... Вот так выглядит: http://prntscr.com/fffypl

Comment: `fflush(stdin)`?! Вы что, плохо себя чувствуете? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: Вы должны понимать, как работают системные вызовы, и что такое сигналы в терминах ОС. Нельзя сделать того, что вы хотите. Читайте посимвольно, используя напрямую `read()`, который, кстати говоря, может вернуть 0 или быть прерван сигналом. (Я убрал слово UNIX выше дабы не расстраивать юнные умы и не вводить лишней нагрузки на детали)

Comment: Да, я плохо себя чувствую, потому что у меня не получается сделать то, что я хочу. Поэтому я и обратился к вам :)

BTW, причём тут юникс, если в метках ясно указана винда?

И, как я говорил, другие варианты (_flushall) не работают. Мне кажется это странным, что такую, казалось бы, банальную задачу нельзя исполнить "обычным" способом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, на англаязычной версии стековерфлоу я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос.

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");
scanf("%*c");
```

Оно таки позволяет очистить буфер. Хоть я и до сих пор не понимаю, почему это нельзя сделать какой-нибудь встроенной функцией (или я о ней не знаю), но это работает.

UPD: всё ещё могут быть некоторые проблемы: если строка уложилась в ограничения по размерам (для fgets), то при вызове этого `scanf("%*[^\n]");` программа зависнет, пока пользователь не ткнёт энтер.